# How to show that $m(E_1 \cap E_2)+m(E_1 \cup E_2)=m(E_1)+m(E_2)$?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ measurable sets.

Show that $m(E_1 \cap E_2)+m(E_1 \cup E_2)=m(E_1)+m(E_2)$

if $E_1$ is measurable, for any set A, $m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E_1)+m^*(A \cap E_1^c)$

how can I start?
(sorry my jvs isnt working I cant add correct tag)

Comment: I assume that $m$ is a measure. Things like that should be mentioned in your question. And also what you mean with $m^{*}$.

Comment: 23 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assumption: $m$ denotes measure, $m^*$ denotes outer measure.)

You can decompose
$$
E_1\cup E_2=(E_1\backslash E_2)\cup(E_2\backslash E_1)\cup(E_1\cap E_2)\tag{*}
$$
then use the additive property (3 times).

---

To be more explicit:
\begin{gather*}
E_1=(E_1\backslash E_2)\cup(E_1\cap E_2)\implies m(E_1)=m(E_1\backslash E_2)+m(E_1\cap E_2),\\
E_2=(E_2\backslash E_1)\cup(E_1\cap E_2)\implies m(E_2)=m(E_2\backslash E_1)+m(E_1\cap E_2).
\end{gather*}
So
$$
m(E_1)+m(E_2)=m(E_1\cap E_2)+[m(E_1\backslash E_2)+m(E_2\backslash E_1)+m(E_1\cap E_2)].
$$
Now use the decomposition given in (*).

Comment: thanks. is this $m(E_1 \cup E_2)=m(E_1)-m(E_1\cap E_2 )+m(E_2)-m(E_1 \cap E_2)+m(E_1 \cap E_2)$ ?

Comment: $m=m^*$ because of measurability right?

Comment: @lyme Do not use subtraction here. That gives troubles if you deal with $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$E_{1}\cup E_{2}=\left(E_{1}\backslash E_{2}\right)\cup\left(E_{2}\backslash E_{1}\right)\cup\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)$$
Consequently: $$m\left(E_{1}\cup E_{2}\right)+m\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)=m\left(E_{1}\backslash E_{2}\right)+m\left(E_{2}\backslash E_{1}\right)+2m\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)$$

$$E_{1}=\left(E_{1}\backslash E_{2}\right)\cup\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)\text{ and } E_{2}=\left(E_{2}\backslash E_{1}\right)\cup\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)$$
Consequently: $$m\left(E_{1}\right)+m\left(E_{2}\right)=m\left(E_{1}\backslash E_{2}\right)+m\left(E_{2}\backslash E_{1}\right)+2m\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)$$

So the RHS of the equations is the same. This allows the conclusion: $$m\left(E_{1}\cup E_{2}\right)+m\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)=m\left(E_{1}\right)+m\left(E_{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate with respect to the measure $m$ the pointwise identity $$\mathbf 1_{E_1\cup E_2}+\mathbf 1_{E_1\cap E_2}=\mathbf 1_{E_1}+\mathbf 1_{E_2}.$$